# .Net Framework 4.7 and different versions of components

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have just installed `System.Net.Http` via Nuget. Package has installed `System.IO` (4.1.1.0). However `System.IO` already exists within `.Net Framework 4.7`, but in version 4.0.0.0.

Why does this package is included in Framework and also exists as a separate package? `.Net Framework 4.7` is young one, so why `System.IO` has been included if it was intended to be a separate package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.IO` package is cross-platform. When using .NET, it just redirects to the .NET assembly. When using .NET Core, it supplies a full System.IO implementation.